# Is there a way to prevent callback until the input `id` is loaded?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash Plotly.

Is there a way to prevent a callback if an Id (at the current moment) used as a INPUT to one of the callbacks.

```
A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback. The id of this object is `some-dropdown` and the property is `value`.
```

Or Is there a way to register all the component id in dash and later it can be used for rendering ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pattern matching](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) callbacks. That's the most flexible solution. If you have a known number of IDs you'll add, then you could also include all of them in the app on initialization, and use callback logic to update them only after the specific trigger occurs. They could be hidden initially as well, then shown later by updating the `style` prop.